# Summary of recurring subseries w/in a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to get a summary of all recurring subseries of a specified length within a pandas Series.  I was wondering if there was a method to find this information within the pandas module.  Furthermore, I would like a means of reporting the frequency of each subseries (perhaps a histogram?).  Thanks!

For example:

```
    series = 
    0    a
    1    b
    2    b
    3    b
    4    a
    5    b
    6    b
    7    a
    8    b
    9    a

    subseries_frequency(series, 3)
```

would return:

```
    [a,b,b] = 2
    [b,b,b] = 1
    [b,b,a] = 2
    [b,a,b] = 2
    [a,b,a] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pred = lambda t: not t[-1] != t[-1] # predicate to drop the partial ones
>>> iter = (ts.shift(-j) for j in range(3)) 
>>> Counter(filter(pred, zip(*iter)))
Counter({('a', 'b', 'b'): 2, ('b', 'a', 'b'): 2, ('b', 'b', 'a'): 2, ('b', 'b', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'b', 'a'): 1})
>>> pd.Series(_)
a  b  a    1
      b    2
b  a  b    2
   b  a    2
      b    1
dtype: int64
```

alternatively,

```
>>> iter = (ts.shift(-j) for j in range(3))
>>> cnt = pd.Series(list(zip(*iter)))
>>> cnt.iloc[:-2].value_counts()
(a, b, b)    2
(b, a, b)    2
(b, b, a)    2
(b, b, b)    1
(a, b, a)    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'm *sure* there is a way (I've seen) to do this staying in pandas/numpy!

Comment: let me know if there is.  i'd imagine with all the analytic capability in those modules, we'd find we don't need to import a Counter (at the very least).